# Missing address fileds in Here-API auto suggest end-point

Tags: here-api

I am using the Here API auto suggest end-point for suggesting cities. Based on this [document](https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/geocoding-and-search-api-v7-api-reference/page/index.html#/paths/%7E1autosuggest/get) I want to get **country**, **countryCode**, **city** and **cityCode** from the response but the address object contains only the *label* field.

Request:

```
https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?apiKey=XXX&at=0,0&q=Eismieze Berlin&lang=en&resultTypes=locality
```

Response:

```
 "items": [
        {
            "title": "Berlin, Germany",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:20187403",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "city",
            "address": {
                "label": "Berlin, Germany"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 52.51604,
                "lng": 13.37691
            },
            "distance": 5971050,
            "mapView": {
                "west": 13.08835,
                "south": 52.33812,
                "east": 13.761,
                "north": 52.6755
            },
            "highlights": {
                "title": [
                    {
                        "start": 0,
                        "end": 6
                    }
                ],
                "address": {
                    "label": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "end": 6
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this request param:
*show=details*

This is an screenshot from the document but they don't write it in the document. Why?

[image]